# How to take text from an HTML element which uses a custom attribute?

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am working on Selenium framework 2.0 Web driver and I would like to get value from a span which has a attribute like data-automation-id. The HTML code is as below

```
<span data-automation-id="SEL_ERR">
  Error Description
</span>
```

Now I want to read the text with in span that has a attribute **data-automation-id** set to SEL_ERR.

Can some one help me in fixing the code as I have already tried the one below but in vain.

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getAttribute("data-automation-id");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple, really. You are currently getting the *very* **first** `span` in the entire document.

How do you know if that is the one you want?

Meet, `.findElements()`. Instead of getting the very first element that meets a locator, it will give you a list of *every* element that meets a criteria.

You've not shared much of the HTML, so I don't know if this is a unique element or not.

However, you have two approaches to this:

1) Use `.findElements` to get *all* the `span` element's and then filter it down to the elements that specifically have the attribute `data-automation-id` with a value of `SEL_ERR`

or (recommended):

2) Use `.findElement` with a selector that specifically targets the element talked about in 1)...if Selenium cannot find it, with a much more targeted selector, then you know it doesn't exist.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[data-automation-id='SEL-ERR']"));
```

or:

3) A modification of 2). If Selenium cannot find it, it'll throw an exception. Exceptions are costly. You can use `.findElements` instead (mentioned in 1)), which will simply return an empty list if it cannot find the element you are looking for:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("span[data-automation-id='SEL-ERR']")).size() != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working with selenium, elements of jquery and javascript.

I have different attributes that belong to a botton that has no ID nor name, just has data-automation-id, as in following examples:

```
<button type="button" 
        data-automationid="FieldRenderer-name" 
        data-selection-invoke="true" 
        class="ms-Link nameField_f59ebb65 clickable_f59ebb65 root-203" 
        title="BD Operacion">BD Operacion</button>
```

DataWerhouse

As you can see, the name data-automationid is repeated

How could I access that element?

This does not work and is the closest I have

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("//button[@data-automation-id='FieldRenderer-name'])[1]")).Click();
```